# How to pretty print nlohmann::json json file? C++

Tags: c++, std, nlohmann-json

How can I pretty print my nlohmann::json json file?

I have tried `o << std::setw(4) << data << std::endl;` like an old stackoverflow question said to do, but I get an error saying:

`main.cpp:39:32: error: no member named 'setw' in namespace 'std'`

`o << std::setw(4) << data ...`

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: You need `#include <iomanip>` for `setw`  to work